# GetThreadDescription() -> What is the proper declaration in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

What is the proper method declaration / DllImport for [GetThreadDescription()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription) for C#?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UIntPtr GetThreadDescription(UIntPtr hThread, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszThreadDescription);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern UIntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);

   public static void Suspend(this Process process)
    {
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
        {
            var pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thread.Id);
            if (pOpenThread == UIntPtr.Zero)
            {
                break;
            }
            string threaddescription = string.Empty;
            GetThreadDescription(pOpenThread, out threaddescription);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thread Description: " + threaddescription);
            SuspendThread(pOpenThread);
        }
    }
```

The string it returns is empty. Changing the MarshalAs to different types of strings has, thus far, yielded nothing. I checked pinvoke.net, and could not find it.

Comment: Have you tried `LPWStr`?

Comment: Is this really a question about C++?

Comment: I have tried LPWStr. And this is a question regarding C++, in so far as one needs to be knowledgeable in C++ to understand the data types and method imports. ^_^

Comment: The storage for the string has to be released with LocalFree().  That requires declaring the parameter as `out IntPtr`, use Marshal.PtrToStringUni() to obtain the string.  And call LocalFree.